# call function only on text edit of qstandard Item in QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I've been looking for the simplest way to call a function only when a qstandardItem's text is editted. I was using onItemChange, but I need a way of separating changes such as check box tick, enable / disable from text edit.

I found examples saying I had to re-implement data() and setData() and I've seen examples on stack overflow. I tried copying them but so far I haven't been able to get what I want.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView,QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
class Main(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setColumnCount(1)
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem("asdf")
        item.setCheckable(True)
        item.setCheckState(2)
        item.isEditable()
        self.model.appendRow([item])
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.on_data_changed)

    @pyqtSlot("QModelIndex", "QModelIndex", "QVector<int>")
    def on_data_changed(self, a, b, c):
        print (a,b,c, a.data())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What does *but it's too generic unfortunately* mean?

Comment: too generic means. I need to know what exactly what has changed. OnItemChange will be called for any change, but I need to be able to separate other changes (checkbox, enable/disable, colour) from text edit changes.

Comment: I recommend you point that out in your post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of the signal indicates the roles that were modified, and that information is used to know if the text was modified or not.

```
@pyqtSlot("QModelIndex", "QModelIndex", "QVector<int>")
def on_data_changed(self, topLeft, bottomRight, roles):
    if Qt.DisplayRole in roles:
        print(topLeft.data())
```

Comment: Yep that looks like exactly what I need, if I use that pyqt crashes:
Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
Have you seen that before?

Comment: @ChristopherRussell 1) You have copied all my code, you will see that I have changed the name of some variables to make the code more readable 2) have you added `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt`? 3) I recommend running in the console or CMD to get more information about the error since a numerical code does not help at all

Comment: I copied the code, thanks for fixing the readability issue. Adding from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt fixes the crashing. But I noticed for me roles is an empty list.

Comment: @ChristopherRussell What is your OS?, what version of PyQt5 do you use and how did you install it?

Comment: Windows 10, pyqt 5.9.6, using anaconda python 3.7

Comment: @ChristopherRussell It's probably a behavior from an old version of Qt, have you tried updating pyqt5? If you are going to update pyqt5 then I recommend not using anaconda as it has many limitations with Qt, in addition to other bugs.

Comment: I noticed the issue in the past too. According to [this qtbug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63766), the third argument of `dataChanged` was not added to QStandardItemModel in earlier Qt 5 versions, and it was fixed starting with version 5.11. The problem is that the model's `itemChanged` didn't support the `roles` argument, and `dataChanged` reflected the same behavior accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [QtBug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63766), the third `dataChanged` argument was never implemented for QStandardItemModel until Qt 5.11 was released.

If you need to provide backward compatibility, a workaround would require (at least) to create a subclass of QStandardItem, override the `setData()` method and use [`setItemPrototype()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItemPrototype), then any new item has to be an instance of the new subclass.

Luckily, `setData` is a public function, and you can use monkey patching as a workaround patch to overwrite the default implementation.

Also, you might probably want to use the patch only for the Qt versions it should be applied to (<Qt 5.11), so you also need to check the version before applying it.

```
# add this at the very beginning of your code, just after the imports, for *any* 
# script that needs to directly use QStandardItem and QStandardItemModel classes

if int(QT_VERSION_STR.split('.')[1]) < 11:
    def setDataFix(self, value, role):
        if not self.model():
            return QtGui.QStandardItem._setData(self, value, role)
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            role = Qt.DisplayRole
            roles = [Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole]
        else:
            roles = [role]
        for _role, _value in self.model().itemData(self.index()).items():
            if _role == role:
                if _value == value:
                    return
                break
        # store the current signal block state
        block = self.model().signalsBlocked()
        # block signal emissions
        self.model().blockSignals(True)
        QtGui.QStandardItem._setData(self, value, role)
        # restore previous signal block state
        self.model().blockSignals(block)
        index = self.model().indexFromItem(self)
        # actually emit the signal *from the model*
        self.model().dataChanged.emit(index, index, roles)
    
    QtGui.QStandardItem._setData = QtGui.QStandardItem.setData
    QtGui.QStandardItem.setData = setDataFix
```

Alternatively, you can use plain simple subclasses, but you obviously need to remember to *always* use the custom subclass when adding new elements programmatically, and use [`setItemPrototype`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setItemPrototype) on the model (to ensure that new items that are internally created always use your subclass, which usually happens with drag&drop events).

```
class StandardItem(QtGui.QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.customRoles = {}

    def clone(self):
        return StandardItem(self)

    def setData(self, value, role):
        if not self.model():
            return super().setData(value, role)
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            role = Qt.DisplayRole
            roles = [Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole]
        else:
            roles = [role]
        for _role, _value in self.model().itemData(self.index()).items():
            if _role == role:
                if _value == value:
                    return
                break
        block = self.model().signalsBlocked()
        self.model().blockSignals(True)
        super().setData(value, role)
        self.model().blockSignals(block)
        index = self.model().indexFromItem(self)
        self.model().dataChanged.emit(index, index, roles)


class Main(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setColumnCount(1)
        self.model.setItemPrototype(StandardItem())
        item = StandardItem("asdf")
        # ...
```

Obviously, in this case, you should consider the version requirements and eventually decide how to provide the default QStandardItemModel or the *fixed* version with the item prototype.

Note: I've tested the above code with very simple cases, you might need to do some deeper checking (and *always* keep in mind that a patching has been done), as it usually happen with workarounds like this:

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. This is really useful. I've used you're second example, and can now see the roles returned. But the value data for the QStandardItem isn't updated. For example when I type in a different word on the QStandardItem it stays at "asdf" do I need to add something else to the setData function?

Comment: @ChristopherRussell sorry, I forgot to actually update the item data. See the update.

Comment: Yep that works now!

is self.model().dataChanged.emit(index, index, roles) only usable from PyQT5? I noticed when I tried to use PyQt4 it gives an error:

 TypeError: QAbstractItemModel.dataChanged[QModelIndex, QModelIndex].emit(): argument 2 has unexpected type 'list'

It's not my choice to use pyqt4, some of  the things I do is constricted by the environment at my work.

Comment: @ChristopherRussell Yes, the third argument was introduced with Qt5, and with Qt4 there were only the first two arguments (`topLeft` and `bottomRight`). Note that in both versions `dataChanged` is not overloaded, so there's no point in using the `[*argTypes]` pointer syntax. If you need to provide version compatibility just build the arguments as a tuple (or list) and use the version to decide what arguments use, for example: `QAbastractItemModel.dataChanged.emit(*args[:(3 if QtVersion == 5 else 2)])`

Comment: That makes sense, but does that mean you can't pass the roles argument in pyqt4 ?

Comment: Exactly: as the [`dataChanged` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) reports, Qt4 doesn't support further arguments. The only possibility is to subclass the model and create another custom signal to provide that argument, but that would only work for actively (*programmatically*) emitted signals. You could emit that signal by yourself (most importantly, within a `setData()` override), but there's no guarantee that it'll be emitted for any case it's usually automatically emitted, especially for private methods usually unaccessible from PyQt.